# Bad Gateway Error on running FastAPI application on IIS

Tags: azure, iis, iis-10, windows-server-2019, bad-gateway

I'm trying to deploy FastAPI app on IIS.
I followed [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/configure-web-apps-for-iis-windows?view=vs-2019) from Microsoft.

My web.config looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
     <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="PythonHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <httpPlatform processPath="c:\Python\Python310\python.exe"
                  arguments="uvicorn main:app"
                  stdoutLogEnabled="true"
                  startupTimeLimit="60"
                  processesPerApplication="16">
      <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="TEMPLATE_STRING" value="some-random-string-text" />
      </environmentVariables>
    </httpPlatform>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

When I'm trying to browse the application, I'm getting an error

```
HTTP Error 502.3 - Bad Gateway

There was a connection error while trying to route the request.

Most likely causes:

1. The CGI application did not return a valid set of HTTP errors. 
2. A server acting as a proxy or gateway was unable to process the request due to an error in a parent gateway.
```

[image: IIS Error]

Can someone point out to me in correct direction. It's my first time working with Windows Server (2019) and IIS (10).

Comment: Yes, I tried it in command line and it runs the app properly.

Comment: Make sure the IUSR and IS_IUSRS has permission to access the folder of application pool. By the way, did you set any url rewrite rule at server level or use reverse proxy in ARR module?

Comment: Yes, I verified. The access is giving to both Users

Comment: @vrunnn have you successfully deployed FastApi on IIS?